# How forecast values using ARIMAX model in Python?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to fit ARIMAX model on train sample (endogenous and exogenous variables) and then forecast using exogenous variables (they are available). I am using `statsmodels` module in Python.

I have the following code:

```
#split datasets
df_train = df.iloc[:100]
df_test= df.iloc[100:104]

# Define the model
model = ARIMA(endog= df_train['y'], exog=df_train[['x1', 'x2']], order=(2,0,2))
# Fit the model
results = model.fit()

#predict for the next 5 periods
results.predict(steps = 5,  exog = df_test[['pc1', 'pc2']])
```

Unfortunately, seems it predicts in-sample fit using train dataset but not test dataset, because there are 100 prediction points.

If there is 2 lags in the model, so should I append last 2 points of `y` from train dataset or should not (`results` somehow preserves information about last value of `y`)?

Similar question I already found, however, they were related to R.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `forecast` method:

```
results.forecast(steps=5,  exog=df_test[['pc1', 'pc2']])
```